# Issue with jquery load function and jquery form ajaxsubmit in ie7, firefox5

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-forms-plugin, jquery-load, firefox-5

I am using a comment section in my form and that is loaded using jquery "load" function. Inside that loaded html, I have document.ready function and jquery form ajax submit function.

When we try to submit a comment in ie7 or firefox5 it is not working. Instead it shows a new page with comment section contents.

We though it is because some issue with Ajax submit and when we traced it further we understand that none of the javascript inside the loaded html is not working in ie7 or firefox5.

Inside the loaded html, there is a document ready function. I put alert message there. Chrome and firefox4 were showing that alert as and when that comment section is loaded. But this alter was not showing in ie7 or firefox5. But the comment section was loaded.

For this reason, comment posting is also not working in those browsers.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you hold a doc. ready in an ajax request? 
you could wait to sucess and then call a function inside your ajax snippet, maybe try to upload some of it to http://jsfiddle.net/